# Integrating Magnolia in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, magnolia

I am new to magnolia and Trying to find out the ways to integrate into Spring MVC.

Can I run magnolia and springs on two different machines?.If so, How Blossom plugin will communicate between these servers.

I seen different documents but all are giving the embedded magnolia in spring MVC.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how you can run Magnolia and Spring on two different machines. But you can always install the blossom module in your Magnolia instance and use Spring MVC through Blossom.

On this [link](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module) you will find the documentation on the Blossom module.
And [here](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Blossom+-+Fully+working+example) you will find a fully working example of Blossom + Magnolia. 
Using Blossom is not hard, and it gives you all the benefits of using the Spring framework with just few little adaptions to the CMS prospective.

Comment: The fully working example page is quite outdated though, you'd be better off following the steps here https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Getting+started+with+Blossom